# Google maps api exception

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

The exception below is increasing with time.

```java
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.ap cannot be stored in an array of type com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.ap[]
```

But I have no idea of what is going on. This issue is happening mainl in devices with Android 8.0 and 8.1.

Dependencies:

App:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Module:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
```

Comment: Even I encountered this crash. Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: The only information I have got about this issue until now is this link, the issue tracker from google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213134272